# Copy operations in shuffle and sort phase of MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop2

I am quite confused about that in Shuffle and Sort phase, Job with m mappers and r reducers involves up to mr copy operations. Which scenario will the copy operations reach maximum value m*r?

Could anyone illustrate it?

Comment: @Mikel could you help

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 3 mappers and 1 reducer. Each mapper task outputs 1 file (sorted by key) that is written to the local filesystem of where the `map` function ran from. So, we will have 3 such output files spread around the cluster.

Since reducers do not take advantage of data locality optimisation, and since we have only 1 reducer - it will need to copy the 3 different output files that each mapper task produced across the network.

Hence, there are `m x n = 3 x 1 = 3` copy operations involved in this scenario.